# How could I reason that $P=V^2 \div R$ because $P = iV$ and $V=iR$?

Tags: substitution

I'm trying to teach myself simple electronic formulas. I haven't done algebra in awhile, and I'm very rusty.

I know that $P = iV$, and $V = iR$, therefore, $P = i^2R$.

How could I figure out that $P = V^2 \div R$, because I know $P = i^2R$?

Is there a name for the trick used? I would like to find out more about it.

Comment: $$i = \dfrac{P}{V}, i = \dfrac{V}{R}$$ So $$\dfrac{P}{V} = \dfrac{V}{R}$$ Can you continue?

Comment: To the extent that there's a 'name' for this, it's that you're eliminating $i$ in favor of $V$. (Whereas in your original work you eliminated $V$ in favor of $i$.) But it's such a standard operation that one usually doesn't name it.

Comment: @Moo thanks! I can see that $P = (V \div R) ^2 R = V^2 \div R$ now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that since current equals voltage divided by resistance, IE $i=V \div R$.

$P=i^2R = (V \div R)^2 R = V^2\div R$